# If I upgrade Ubuntu from an EOL version to a supported version will my data will lost?

Tags: upgrade

If I upgrade Ubuntu from an EOL version to a supported version will my data will lost?

Answer (score 1):

The data will be never lost during an update: your data is stored in `/home` directory, and the upgrade affects the other parts of the system. What might be lost are your app settings and your desktop preferences (it didn't happened never when I made release upgrades, through.).

If you are paranoid, backup your important data to an external HDD, disconnect it, and make the upgrade afterwards.

Comment: i m not having external HDD to take backup , can i upgrade it then?...Pls suggest me

Comment: @khanthegeek Operating without a backup is like walking a tightrope without a net. Definitely **NOT** Recommended. Regardless, Frantique is correct.